# Has anyone here integrated Team Explorer Everywhere with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, tfs, team-explorer

I'm starting Macintosh development and I'm in a Microsoft shop where we're using Team Foundation Server.

I've learned that there's no explicit/official TFS client for any non-Windows platform, and that the best option is to use Team Explorer Everywhere, formerly Teamprise (Microsoft bought them and rebranded it) and either the command-line client or the Eclipse plugin. There's no Xcode plugin because, as revealed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313/what-is-the-best-way-to-integrate-tfs-version-control-with-xcode), Apple doesn't give out enough info to be able to integrate into Xcode. That answer was given by [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6438/martin-woodward) who appears to be part of Teamprise (the question was asked before the Microsoft acquisition it seems.)

Fair enough, but one comment he made intrigued me:

> That said, we do have a number of customers who ... have macros inside XCode that perform basic check-out and get operations in-conjunction with the TFS command line (tf).

Has anyone here done this? And if so is there anything they can share with the group?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself.  But you should be able to use [SVNBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) with your Mac to TFS (Install SVNBridge on either the TFS server or another Windows machine.)

Comment: Mathew is correct that you should be able to use any SVN or Mercurial client with TFS using the Bridge.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this answer is helpful or dispiriting - it suggests that you'd be heading down the Applescript route.

[How Can I Automate Tasks in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885890/how-can-i-automate-tasks-in-xcode)

If I was going to do it, I'd use Applescript to trigger a shell script (presuming 'tf' is a Unix commandline utility for accessing a tf server).